# SharePoint Framework SPFx - Using PNP js How to get and save value in Yes/No sharepoint column

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-custom-property-pane

I am creating custom webpart in SPFx. I have a yes/no column. I have to use PNP js to get the value, when that check box got selected.

That value I should save it in SharePoint column as `Yes`, if its unchecked it should be saved as `No`.

Can some one give me the code.

I tried with `.prop("checked" "checked)` and `.attr("checked", true)`. Both are throwing error its not accepting in PNPjs.

Please assist me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In REST, booleans (YesNo choice) fields should be set as 0/1 i.e 0 for No and 1 for yes.

So, you can use the below sample code. We will first check if the checkbox is checked. If it is checked, will set the value in our code to 1, if unchecked will set it to 0 and after that will add/update our list item. Please use the internal columns names for this making the REST queries :

```
var checkboxValue = $('#checkboxId').is(":checked") ? 1 : 0;

pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Custom List").items.add({
    Title: "Title",
    BoolField : checkboxValue
}).then((i: ItemAddResult) => {
    console.log(i);
});
```

Comment: any update on this @nagarajan ? If it helped you, you can [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by ticking the checkmark besides the answer ! It will remove this question from list of unanswered questions, thanks :)